# Accessing a second NSDictionary in the plist?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, plist, nsdictionary

I was wondering how I could access the second NSDictionary in my plist other then the root dictionary, what I would like is to have a string in the second dictionary to show up in the console right now I'm getting all of them. Here's my code, console and plist.

My Plist. (its name is Multi.plist)
[image: My Plist]

My code.

```
    NSString *pathForPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Multi"    ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathForPlist];

     NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Abs"]);
```

And what my console is spitting out right now.
[image]

So after looking at that, I'll explain again what I would like, instead of having all of the contents of the Abs NSDictionary being in the console, I would like just to show the title string which lies within the Dictionary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Abs entry is a dictionary itself, so all you have to do is :

```
NSDictionary * abs = dict[@"Abs"];
NSLog(@"%@", abs[@"title"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *absDict = [dict objectForKey:@"Abs"]);
NSString *title = [absDict objectForKey:@"title"]);
NSLog(@"Title: %@", title);
```

Comment: yes this dose work but i found that @shaish response was a bit better but thank you anyways